# Security Tab missings in Project Server 2013 (PWA) Settings

Tags: security, project-server

I am NOT seeing the security link in my default PWA site in Project Server 2013.

Following is my site

[image]

Do i need to enable this from somewhere else?

Following is a Project Server 2013 PWA Site with Security link that I found on internet.

[image]

Comment: may be you are using SharePoint permission mode not Project server permission mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Project Server 2013 / 2016, There is two permission mode:

- SharePoint Permission Mode.(Default)
- Project Server Permission Mode.

By default, Project server activates the SharePoint Permission mode, and in this case, the security section does not appear in PWA Settings. where The security section is only activated with the Project Server Permission Mode.

**To switch to Project permission Mode run the following command**

```
Set-SPPRojectPermissionMode -Url 'PWA URL' -AdministratorAccount 'domain\adminaccount' -Mode ProjectServer
```

**Note:** All settings of the current mode will be lost once you switch to another mode. For more details check [Missing Security Section in PWA Settings](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/07/missing-security-in-pwa-settings/)

Also, I advise you to check [the difference between SharePoint Permission Mode and Project Server Permission Mode in Project Server 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/23/sharepoint-permission-mode-vs-project-server-permission-mode-in-project-server-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to start

> Window Powershell
>
> add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
>
> set-spprojectpermissionMode
>
> url:Add your Site Url
>
> Mode:ProjectServer
>
> ENTER